# Automatic column mapping in UPDATE step

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

For inserts, if source and target columns are the same, no mapping or "select values" step is required. But for updates, there seems to be a need to specify list of update fields.

My concern is around manually updating the KTR's each time a source table is altered for columns. Is there a way to enable automatic mapping during the Update step? See screenshot for the "update fields", automatic mapping would mean that update fields section can be left blank.

[image: Update step screenshot]

Comment: Hello @kulfy I am using pentaho 6.0.1 version and haven't seen any way to automatically get the table metadata from table when the definition is updated.

Comment: @Novice, I am on a pretty old version, 5.0.1, thanks for confirming the behavior from a latest version! I can't seem to understand why there wouldn't be a default option that would automatically map metadata unless otherwise stated. In effect, default = update all columns and specify a list if choosing few.

Comment: well its an open source tool so i think nobody might have needed such requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are good reason NOT to do so.

Believe me, having a robot to change your ktr is not a good idea. And there are good reasons not to change often the column names in an OPAP schema, unless you like to be in conflict with the Reports Designers and, even worse, with the Dashboard and Front End Javascript guys.

So if a press button is not a solution for you, because maybe you have 1000 tables to update, what you can do is to use a `Metadata Injection` step. You'll find nice examples on [Diethard Steiner's blog](http://diethardsteiner.github.io/pdi/2015/10/31/Transformation-Executor-Record-Groups.html) or  [Jens Bleuel's blog](http://kettle.bleuel.com/2016/04/14/pentaho-6-1-part-2/). In two words, you make the `Update` metadata dynamic, but you first have to examine each table to get the column names.